# What do you call a person who prefers the company of the opposite sex over their own (not in anyway sexual)

Tags: meaning

Example: a guy who is used to being around the opposing sex and has been for a long time, therefore he will usually be more comfortable with female friends than male ones

(I'm not good at explaining things and I have searched all over for a good word that describes this attitude so I hope you get gist of What I'm saying)

Comment: [heterosocial?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterosociality#Terminology) It's not actually a commonly used word; you'd probably get a few strange looks if you tried to use it in conversation. Can you please add to your question, in what context you want to use this word?

Comment: I think this question may have been asked before. I'm on my mobile so I can't find it though.